# PowerShell System.Xml.Linq Unable to Parse XML to HTML

Tags: html, xml, linq, powershell, powershell-4.0

I am currently trying to use to use this script provided to format an HTML table (https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-HTML-Notificatio-e1c5759d#content)

I managed to get most of the functions to work but cant get the Add-HTMLTableColor function to work.

The code I am using is the following:

```
$params = @{
Column = "Used (GB)"
ScriptBlock = {[double]$args[0] -gt [double]$args[1]}}

Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | New-HTMLTable -setAlternating $false | Add-HTMLTableColor -Argument 40 -attrValue "background-color:#FFFF99;" @params
```

However, it throws a Error:  Namespace incorrect.

I dug into the script provided on TechNet and noticed that the Parse function of System.Xml.Linq returns on big XML node instead of separate XML node when HTML is passed on. It does state that it requires System.Xml.Linq v2 and I have only managed to find the dll for v3 and v4?

Is the incorrect version the root of the problem or is there another reason why it cant manage to parse the HTML into XML properly? Or is it another problem completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested another library that uses the System.Xml.Linq dll file from the system. It returned an error also when attempting to use the dll as well.

After replacing the Linq dll requirement with an assmebly import of the Linq functionality, both functions in the both library was working.

As such, it is determined that the Linq dll is not fully compatible with PowerShell and is unable to perfectly parse HTML to XML.

The solution is to either use custom assmebly import (such as the one in this  [script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Colorize-HTML-Table-Cells-2ea63acd)) or to use a different library all together.